# Trouble with nawk and OFS in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, pattern-matching, design-patterns, nawk

I am working on a script to extract the processor set number followed by the processor ids that fall under that processor set in Solaris in bash shell:

Here is the output I want to extract from: (contents of $output)

```
user processor set 1: processors 0 1
user processor set 2: processors 2 8 9
user processor set 3: processors 3 4 5 6 7
```

Desired output is:

```
1: 0 1
2: 2 8 9
3: 3 4 5 6 7
```

The code i wrote using nawk:

```
print $output | nawk '                                 
BEGIN { ORS="\n" ; OFS = " " }
{
print$4; print OFS
for (i=6;i<=NF;i++)
print $i
}'
```

obtained output:

```
1: 
0 
1
2: 
2 
8 
9
3:  
3 
4 
5 
6 
7
```

Can anyone help and let me know what I am missing from obtaining the desired output .
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Idea to use OFS and ORS are obtained from this tutorial: [tutorial link](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORS` is already set to `"\n"` by default. Since you want to use multiple print statements you'll want to set it to the empty string since there's an implicit `print ORS` after any print statement.

```
print $output | awk '
    BEGIN { ORS=""; }
    {
        print $4;
        for (i=6;i<=NF;i++)
            print " " $i;
        print "\n";
    }'
```

You could also do this with cut:

```
print $output | cut -d ' ' -f 4,6-
```

Comment: Thanks John... that was an awesome catch ...I dint know about the implicit print ORS ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
print $output | nawk '                                 
BEGIN { ORS="\n" ; OFS = " " }
{
outrec = ""
for (i=6;i<=NF;i++)
    outrec = outrec " " $i
    print $4 " " outrec
}'
```